# SMS client for Windows

Tags: windows, mobile, sms

I'm looking for an application that will sync from my desktop/laptop to my phone over Bluetooth or USB, and allow me to read and compose/send SMS messages from the computer.

Software should be compatible at least down to Windows 7 SP1 and up to Windows 10. On the phone side, I'd prefer it to be platform-agnostic, but at least need compatibility with Windows 10 Mobile running on a Microsoft Lumia 950.

Considering that we can compose/send and receive SMS via other Bluetooth-connected devices such as car stereos and smart-watches, I imagine this must be possible. I'm just having a hard time finding anything good out there for it.

I'm really not comfortable with is having my SMS going to/through (yet) another third-party. Probably the main reason I'm looking for a direct interface via Bluetooth/USB.

Comment: I use Google Voice, I find it nice to avoid this kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are asking for but [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com) uses the net to allow you to send and see SMS messages on your phone through both an App on your PC and via a chrome plug-in as well as using the app on your phone/computer to send pushbullet messages.

- Free for up to 100 SMSs a month *$4.99/month or £39.9/year for pro unlimited*
- Android
- iPhone
- Windows
- Chrome plugin
- Firefox " "
- Opera   " "
- Safari  " "

It can also send picture messages MMS.  Optionally you can set [end-to-end encryption](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2015/08/11/end-to-end-encryption/) between **your** devices for the Notification Mirroring, Universal Copy & Paste and SMS features, *(at the time of writing only for Android, Chrome & Windows Desktop more platforms promised soon)*, so that your data travelling from one device to the other via their servers is secure.

Plus some community developed versions for Windows Phone, etc.

The one point where it is not exactly what you described is that it does not use USB or Bluetooth - it uses your data channel to access your phone - not a problem if your phone is WiFi enabled and you have access to the network but you might incur data charges if you are roaming.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the other down-side I'm really not comfortable with is having my SMS going to/through (yet) another third-party. Probably the main reason I'm looking for a direct interface via Bluetooth/USB.

Comment: @Iszi - pushbullet uses end to end encryption for SMS 0 I did have a couple of ways of doing what you are asking on Windows 10 but they both stopped working after a few days.

Comment: @SteveBarnes - There is no contact form on their website.  I wanted to know if the messages go to the phone and then bounce to the web, or does it access them directly

Answer (score 1):

I've been using messages.google.com and/or the MS Phone-Link application.  Messages.google.com works pretty well, but there's only a web version, and MS Phone-Link can occasionally be glitchy.

Although these may work for you, I'm not fully satisfied with either of them, so I'm looking forward to additional answers to this question.